# Query in Api Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to make APIs showing data from two tables, but I'm stuck at this point.

This is my `ApiController`:

```
public function postDetaillog(Request $request)
{
    $response  = array();
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),            
        [
            'id'=> 'required',
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $message = $validator->errors()->all();      

        $result['api_status']  = 0;
        $result['api_message'] = implode(', ',$message);      

        $res = response()->json($result);
        $res->send();
        exit;
    }

    $data = DB::table('log_patrols')
        ->where('id', $request->input('id'))
        ->first();

    $site   = asset("uploads").'/';

    $result = DB::table('log_patrol_details')
        ->select("*",DB::raw("concat('$site',photo1) as photo1"),DB::raw("concat('$site',photo2) as photo2"),DB::raw("concat('$site',photo3) as photo3"))
        ->where('id', $request->input('id'))
        ->first();

    if (count($result) == 0) {
        $response['api_status']  = count($result);
        $response['api_message'] = "No data";
    } else {
        $response['api_status']  = 1;
        $response['api_message'] = "success";
        $response['data']        = $data;
        $response['result']      = $result;
    }
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

first table
[image: this the table]
second table
[image: second table]

Whenever I try to get the results, it always gives me `0 = no data`

[image: this the result]

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried that query on mysql? Why are you using `CONCAT()`?

Comment: i use concat for give url to my photo

Comment: or do u have soution ? for me ?

Comment: Make `dump($result);` and check output.

Comment: where i input this code ? can u give me more specific ?

Comment: Before You do `if (count($result) == 0) {`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you get is a collection you may use `if ($result->count() == 0)` to check if it is empty.

Change as follows:

```
if ($result->count() == 0) {
    $response['api_status']  = 0; // Don't use useless logic 
    $response['api_message'] = "No data";
} else {
    $response['api_status']  = 1;
    $response['api_message'] = "success";
    $response['data']        = $data;
    $response['result']      = $result;
}
```

Comment: i try to use that but its result error "Call to a member function count() on a non-object" any other ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: iam use 5.1. sorry for late info ^^

Comment: Well, forget what I said, `count()` does not work since you are using `first()`. My mistake. It seems the problem must be in your query. could you please try to `dd($request->all());` right before the `$result` assignment? Let me know what you get.

Comment: um same, i get null object

Comment: thanks for your attention, my code is was not wrong, i only wrong in input ID, and the id is doesnt have data's so there only show null and no data. thanks bro